# Removing Polyline for Google Map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I want to remove d polyline in google map , but it remain I have try everything  as you can see from the code also  I check the debug area and the rectangle.map is nil?? but it still appear on the map and I do not want to user the clear method is work correct but I have other element on the map that I dint want to remove

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.0))
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.2))
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.2))
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))
        let rectangle = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        var oldPolylineArr = [GMSPolyline]()
        oldPolylineArr.append(rectangle)

        if self.count == 0 {
            rectangle.map = self.googelMap
            print("count \(self.count)")
            self.count = 1
        }
        else if self.count == 1 {
            //rectangle.map = nil
            //path.removeAllCoordinates()
            self.count = 0
            for p in (0 ..< oldPolylineArr.count) {
                oldPolylineArr[p].map = nil
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is local variable ( Inside the function )

```
var oldPolylineArr = [GMSPolyline]()
oldPolylineArr.append(rectangle)
```

you need to make it an instance var , as it holds the last one  , so get this line out

```
var oldPolylineArr = [GMSPolyline]()
```

Then to clear all do

```
oldPolylineArr.forEach { $0.map = nil }
```

after that set your new created polyline

```
rectangle.map = self.googelMap
```

---

This will add a polyline and remove the old

```
class ViewController:UIViewController {

    var oldPolylineArr = [GMSPolyline]() 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func addPolyAndRemoveOld() {

        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
            // remove here
            oldPolylineArr.forEach { $0.map = nil }

            // add new
            let path = GMSMutablePath()
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.0))
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.45, longitude: -122.2))
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.2))
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.36, longitude: -122.0))
            let rectangle = GMSPolyline(path: path) 
            oldPolylineArr.append(rectangle)
            rectangle.map = self.googelMap
         }
      }
 }
```

Comment: I am new to swift I you dont mind can you give the code?

Comment: do you want 1 polyline at a time ??

Comment: I have an array of point and form them I will draw the lines the I will remove this lines

Comment: thank you are a live saver the code work like a charm